# Using Jquery to animate logo in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text that I want to be swapped out for a logo once the user scrolls past a certain point. I already have this working

https://jsfiddle.net/ybh22msj/

The issue is that it just swaps the two items. I actually want a nice animation in. Maybe the logo appearing from the top and pushing out the text. I'm not really sure how to achieve this.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()> 200) {
        $('#logo2').show();
        $('#logo1').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#logo2').hide();
        $('#logo1').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please be more specific. For example, what animation exactly do you want to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Too vague, Google for *jquery effect examples* for inspiration.

Comment: Take at [jquery ui's .show](https://jqueryui.com/show/)

Comment: You should never use .hide() or .show() https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/564443848613847040  EVER

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for simple fade you can use

```
$('#logo2').fadeOut();
$('#logo1').fadeIn();
```

or

```
$('#logo2').slideOut();
$('#logo1').slideIn();
```

for more complex animations you will need to use `animate` [http://api.jquery.com/animate/] and set the options

```
options = {123: 456};
$('#logo2').animate(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fadeOut/fadeIn` to show the fade effect.

```
$('#logo2').fadeOut();
$('#logo2').fadeIn();
```

You can use `slideOut/slideIn` to show the slide effect that will animate the height of the element.

```
$('#logo2').slideOut();
$('#logo2').slideIn();
```

If you want to create your own animation you can use [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ybh22msj/1/

```
$('logo1').fadeOut("slow", function(){ $('#logo2').fadeIn("fast"); });
//and
$('logo2').fadeOut("slow", function(){ $('#logo1').fadeIn("fast"); });
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for?. It uses callbacks so that once it fades out, then the other one fades in.

Thank You.